# Every quadratic form is continuous on the unit circle.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove a proposition below.

\\\\\\\\\\\

[image]

\\\\\\\\\\\\

In the proof, the author claims that $Q$ is continuous on the unit circle.

In order to establish this fact, I first choose one vector $p$ in the unit circle and then aim to show that $Q$ is continuous at $p$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. I want to find $\delta>0$ so that if $||x-p||<\delta$, and $x$ is in the unit circle, then $|Q(x)-Q(p)|<\epsilon$. Note that $||\cdot||$ is the norm defined by the inner product on $V$. Since $Q$ is a quadratic form on $V$, there exists a symmetric bilinear form $H$ on V such that $\forall x\in V$, $Q(x)=H(x,x)$. Here comes the problem. I don't know what's the next step I should take. Is there any inequality that benefits? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn’t $Q$ continuous everywhere?

Comment: If you choose any basis for $V$, $Q$ is a polynomial in the coordinates defined by that basis.  So it's continuous everywhere.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on $V$. There exist an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ for $V$ and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $v\in V$ and $v=xe_1+ye_2, x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then $Q(v)=\lambda_1 x^2+\lambda_2 y^2$. Can you tell how to make use of this fact to establish continuity? Thanks.

Comment: @iamokay: That wouldn't be okay, because the theorem uses the continuity of $Q$ to justify the existence of $e_1$ and $e_2$.  So you would making a circular argument.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Then what do you mean by "a polynomial in the coordinates defined by that basis" in the earlier response? I really need some help. The continuity problem has trapped me so long that I couldn't step any further. I need to get the job done. Please.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a basis $v_1, v_2$ of $V$.  Then any $x \in V$ can be written as $x_1 v_1 + x_2 v_2$ for unique scalars $x_1$ and $x_2$.  These are the *coordinates* on $V$ determined by the basis $v_1, v_2$.  Then
$$
    Q(x) = H(x_1v_1 + x_2v_2,x_1v_1+x_2v_2) = x_1^2 H(v_1,v_1) + 2x_1x_2 H(v_1,v_2) + x_2^2 H(v_2,v_2)
$$
So if we set $a = H(v_1,v_1)$, $b = H(v_1,v_2)$, and $c = H(v_2,v_2)$, then
$$
     Q(x_1v_1 + x_2v_2) = ax_1^2 + 2b x_1 x_2 + c x_2^2.
$$
This means that $Q$ is a polynomial in the coordinates of $x$, and is therefore a continuous function.

If you need to go deeper, show that the coordinate functions $x_1$ and $x_2$ themselves are continuous.  Then use the fact that sums, multiples, and products of continuous functions are continuous to show that $Q$ is.

Comment: Thank you. I need some time to digest the material, especially contiuity of $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: Given $p=p_1v_1+p_2v_2$, is it possible to talk about $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to p}x_1=p_1$, say, the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?